# ANGULAR - SVG as template

Tags: angular, svg

I have a problem with attribute binding to SVG template, because I want to bind data to SVG as template added in @Component(...) decorator.

Base component

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: ''
})
export abstract class BaseSvgComponent {
  @Input() readonly fillColor: string;
  @Input() readonly margin: number;
  @Input() set marketWidth(markerWidth: number) {
    this._marketWidth = markerWidth;
    this.d = `M ${markerWidth - 15} 0 L ${markerWidth - 15} 0 L ${markerWidth - 15} 17 L ${markerWidth} 8.5 Z`;
  }

  get marketWidth(): number {
    return this._marketWidth;
  }

  @Input() readonly message: string;
  @Input() readonly svgWidth: number;
  @Input() readonly xEnd: number;
  @Input() readonly xStart: number;

  d: string;

  protected _marketWidth: number;
}
```

One from few similar SVGs

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { BaseSvgComponent } from '../base-svg/base-svg.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-rectangle-svg',
  templateUrl: './rectangle-svg.component.svg',
  styleUrls: ['./rectangle-svg.component.scss']
})
export class RectangleSvgComponent extends BaseSvgComponent {}
```

SVG as template

```
<svg [attr.width]="svgWidth" height="20">
  <rect
    [attr.fill]="fillColor"
    [attr.width]="xEnd - xStart - 15 - 2"
    [attr.x]="margin"
    y="2"
    rx="5"
    ry="2"
    height="14"
  />

  <text
    [attr.x]="margin + xEnd - xStart - 25"
    y="13"
    text-anchor="end"
  >
    {{ message }}
  </text>

  <path
    [attr.d]="d"
    [attr.fill]="fillColor"
  />
</svg>
```

Property binding is not working, HTML is generated without binded data.
How I can resolve the problem?

Comment: The only thing I notice is that readonly @Inputs don't make much sense. Can you make this simple example break: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wwmgnx?file=src/app/svg/rect.component.ts  It's working for me

Comment: it's looks like work :(. See a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xhyemy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) with your code, check if you has errors in console or use F12 to see the .svg created